# How to create a script to run mysql commands

Tags: shell, mysql

Is it possible to use a shell script to run this following command?

```
mysql -u user
use mydb
delete from mydata where row='xx'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for a "here document":

```
mysql -u user << END_CMDS
use mydb
delete from mydata where row='xx'
END_CMDS
```

The "here document" is a way of putting the SQL in-line inside the script itself. I'm not sure how the user ID's MySQL password plays into this. You'll have to experiment if that user has a password.

The `mysql` invocation can be indented in your shell script, but do not indent the token that ends your "here document", which is END_CMDS in my example above.

Answer (score 2):

That command could help you:

> mysql -u user -p mydb --execute="delete from mydata where row='xx'"

Comment: it's asking me for password and I don't know what password I should enter.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested to examine some of the scripts on my [mythtv-tools](http://taz.net.au/mythtv-tools/) web page.  They are reasonably good examples of running mysql commands from a shell script, and of building up moderately complicated mysql commands (e.g. with multiple WHERE clauses) based on getopt option parsing.

They all use the same basic technique of constructing an SQL string and piping it into `mysql` or `mysql --batch`.

None of them use the `--user` or `--password` options, as any user on the system can trawl through `/proc` (or just run `ps`) and see the login and password in the command-line options.  Instead they rely on the existence of a `~/.my.cnf` file containing login credentials.